# Python: Checking for palindrome returns False for some reason

Tags: python, palindrome

I'm trying to write a program, and one of the things I need to do is to check if a number is a palindrome.
For some reason, what I wrote does not work:

```
flag = True
for j in range(0, len(listnum)):
    for t in range(len(listnum) -1, -1, -1):
        if listnum[j] == listnum[t]:
            flag = True
            print "false"
         else:
            flag = False
            print "false"
            break
if flag == True:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

The print "false"/"true" part is for debugging.
I took this code out of a function I wrote, which is why it says "return True/False".

The number I'm checking is 906609

Comment: Why not to remove the `flag` variable and just return `True`/`False` directly from the inner loop?

Comment: I used to do that, but I tried to look what causes it to return false, which is why I changed some things around including this.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason now that I changed it, it worked.

Comment: Why did it not work when I did the above?

Comment: Your logic is off. Two nested loops mean compare each element with each other - this is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function checks if the last number is different from any other in the list. What you want is probably:

```
def palindrome(listnum):
    for j in range(0, len(listnum)):
        t = len(listnum) - j - 1
        if listnum[j] != listnum[t]:
            return False            

    return True

assert palindrome([9,0,6,6,0,9])
assert palindrome("ABBA")
assert palindrome([])
assert palindrome("1")
assert palindrome([1.0, 2, 1])
assert not palindrome("lolz")
assert not palindrome([1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an answer to why your code doesn't work, but you might be interested to know that there's a much easier way to determine whether a word is a palindrome. By definition, a palindrome is a word that is not changed by reversing it. Hence:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    return word == ''.join(reversed(word))

print is_palindrome('906609') # True
```

The only part of this that may require explanation is the `join`ing. It is necessary because `reversed` returns the letters of the word one by one, so you first need to put them together again.

As pointed out in a comment, another way of writing it is `word == word[::-1]`. It means exactly the same, but is arguably a bit more cryptic.

Comment: well, `word==word[::-1]` would be even "easier".

Comment: Indeed, but `''.join(reversed(word))` is simply `word[::-1]`

Comment: word[::-1] is also 4.3x faster (at least on my Windows 7 PC using 32-bit Python 3.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the nesting of the for loops. It looks like you want to update j and t in lock-step, but instead you're starting with j=0 and then checking all values of t. Then j=1 and you check all values of t again, etc.

Instead of the nested loop, you could use a loop counter to track the distance you're looking into the word and then calculate j and t from that. E.g.

```
for d in range(len(listnum)/2):
    j = d
    t = len(listnum) - d - 1
    #letter equality check here, return if false

return True
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem. The code from propeller worked however I could not understand what made it different.

Comment: @user2240288 Because your loops were nested, you were comparing characters with each other. So, with each iteration of outer loop, the inner one would break with `flag = False` as soon as it finds a character that differs from `listnum[j]`. So, your function was actually checking if the string contains only equal characters (e.g. `777777`).

Comment: @user2240288 Trying to go through a part your of program and doing all the steps manually (on a paper or in a text editor) helps understanding how your code works and what should be changed :)